# User Agent is grayed out on Safari

Tags: safari, user-agent

I am trying to do an IE test using Safari but all of my options under user agent are grayed out.

I'm running an Angular 5 project (ng serve) on Safari v 11.1

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I figured out you have to use the menu from the monitor/screen where you have the Browser window open and NOT the Web Inspector.

**Example:**

You have two monitors:

Monitor 1 has the web page open on Safari.

Monitor 2 has the Web Inspector for said page.

You have to click on `Develop > User Agent` on Monitor 1.

Comment: WTF REALLY , THAT'S A REALLY GOOD DESIGN

Comment: @nick That's Apple for ya

Comment: you can tell that took some time off my life lol

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple "fix", but just in case anyone else had the issue and...like me...didn't try this immediately.

Fully quitting Safari and reopening it resolved the issue for me.